# split function when split charecter present in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the scenario:
I have 6 string varables having some special charecters.
I assigned these 6 strings to an array like this:

```
arr=[str1,str2,str3.....);
arr=escape(arr);
```

because some string variable have special charecters.
After that I am sending this `arr` into other function
and then recive this in other function like this:
var `newarr=unescape(arr);`
Now i want to get all six variables from this **new arr** how can I do this?
Currently i am using split function
like: `.split(',');`

But the problem is that in some variables I have `,` inside, and it's splitted twice, I don't want that.

I have three variables

```
img='/cardfinderservice/services/imageservice/?cardVersionId=16682&amp';

desc= '5% Cash Back on up to $1,500 spent at grocery stores and movie theatres from 4/1/12-6/30/12&lt;br /&gt';

details='Unlimited 1% Cash Back on all other purchases&lt;br /&gt;Up to an additional 10% Cash Back when you shop online at select merchants through Chase&lt;br /&gt;No annual fee and rewards never expire&lt;/p&gt';

Var arr=[img,desc,details];   
arr=escape(arr);   
loadabc(arr);   
function loadabc(arr){    
    var newarr=unescape(arr);   
    newarr=newarr.split(',');   
}
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the array itself? couldn't you just loop through the values and escape each?

Comment: I am passing some special chrecters in these strings

Comment: I have thre varables

img='/cardfinderservice/services/imageservice/?cardVersionId=16682&amp;';
desc= '5% Cash Back on up to $1,500 spent at grocery stores and movie theatres from 4/1/12-6/30/12&lt;br /&gt';
details='Unlimited 1% Cash Back on all other purchases&lt;br /&gt;
 Up to an additional 10% Cash Back when you shop online at select merchants through Chase&lt;br /&gt;
 No annual fee and rewards never expire&lt;/p&gt;';

Var arr=[img,desc,details];
arr=escape(arr);

loadabc(arr);

function loadabc(arr)
{
var newarr=unescape(arr);
newarr=newarr.split(',');

}

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me - if the strings are part of the array you just pass the array object between functions - why do you need to escape it? Can you show example of special chars?

Comment: If i pass these variables without escaping it gave me error for this (').

Comment: img='/cardfinderservice/services/imageservice/?cardVersionId=16682&amp';

desc= '5% Cash Back on up to $1,500 spent at grocery stores and movie theatres from 4/1/12-6/30/12&lt;br /&gt';

details='Unlimited 1% Cash Back on all other purchases&lt;br /&gt;Up to an additional 10% Cash Back when you shop online at select merchants through Chase&lt;br /&gt;No annual fee and rewards never expire&lt;/p&gt';

Comment: Vikas, you do not need to escape the array. If you are having trouble with errors you should rethink what exactly you are trying to do. Arrays have no need to be escaped. There IS another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3hD2Z/)**

```
var arr=[img,desc,details].join('|||');  // join with something special :)
arr=escape(arr);   
loadabc(arr);

function loadabc(arr){    
    var newarr=unescape(arr);   
    newarr=newarr.split('|||'); // instead of comma split by |||
    alert(newarr[1]);           // test tricky one holding a comma
}
```

Comment: yes, your answer may work, but do you want to keep giving programmers the impression that this is the RIGHT thing to do? This is a solution, yet unconventional and bad practice.

Comment: @andbeyond I purely agree with you. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

Lets stop trying to fix his problem with unconventional tactics. Clearly, there is NO need to escape an array, pass it into a function, and unescape it. This is BAD.

If you don't use single quotes in your strings then there is no need for escaping

http://jsfiddle.net/n6haN/

the console log looks fine to me!